# Optional IconData on constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm studying Flutter, so I'm just a newbie.

I tried to create a widget with an optional IconData type parameter in the constructor, but I was getting an error.

I got added "?" in front of the local variable. From then on, I just had to enclose the constructor parameters in "{ }". I've found a way to make it work, but I'm not sure it is the best/correct way to do so.

If you have any tip, I'll be happy to hear it!

That's my code:

```
class Editor extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controlador;
  final String label;
  final String hint;
  final IconData? fieldIcon;

  Editor(
      {required this.controlador,
      required this.label,
      required this.hint,
      this.fieldIcon});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controlador,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24.0,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: label,
          hintText: hint,
          icon: fieldIcon != null ? Icon(fieldIcon) : null,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine, what erro are you getting?

Comment: I think you are talking about "key warning", put super.key in your constructor.

Comment: Hi Claudio. I'm not getting an error actually, I just wanna get some opinions from the professionals :).
Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Nothing inappropriate in my opinion.

---

However, I feel the following checking for is redundant:

```dart
icon: fieldIcon != null ? Icon(fieldIcon) : null,
```

Given that the `icon` property of `InputDecoration` already takes a nullable icon, why not give it just that?

Maybe change the type of `fieldIcon` from `IconData?` to `Icon?` itself. Then, where you consume the icon in the `InputDecoration`, simply give it the nullable `fieldIcon`:

```dart
icon: fieldIcon,
```

But wherever you use this `Editor` widget, remember to give it an `Icon` for `fieldIcon` and not an `IconData`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your support my friend, I'll be testing it now! Best regards!